# How can we implement the same condition with two different values in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

```
    IF [District Parameter] = "All"  THEN  [routes]

   ELSEIF  [District Parameter] = "BARGARH" and [Name of the Recipient District1] = 
   "Khordha" THEN [c.origin to depo route]

   ELSEIF [District Parameter] = "BARGARH" and [Name of the Recipient District1] = 
  "Khordha"
   THEN [c.depo to receipent route]  

  ELSEIF [District] = [District Parameter] THEN [routes]

   END
```

In the above code [routes], [c.depo to receipent route] and [c.origin to depo route] are spatial calculated fields. You can see two elseif conditions have the same condition with two different values. But When I executed the above code only one elseif condition is getting executed. Kindly give some solution, I want to implement both elseif conditions with two different values.

Comment: Not sure entirely what the desired outcome is but for any IF / ELSE IF calculation, once a condition is TRUE, it stops. So the second ELSEIF will never be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In single calculation it is difficult to achieve. Not sure of the question though. You need to create some flag to distinguish between 2 elseif.

Below solution you can try.

create 3 calculated field to achieve this.

calculated field1-
IF [District Parameter] = "All"  THEN  [routes]

ELSEIF  [District Parameter] = "BARGARH" and [Name of the Recipient District1] =
"Khordha" THEN [c.origin to depo route]

ELSEIF [District] = [District Parameter] THEN [routes]

END

calculated field2-

IF  [District Parameter] = "BARGARH" and [Name of the Recipient District1] =
"Khordha"
THEN [c.depo to receipent route]

END

calculated field3-

if isnull(field1) then field2 else field1 end

Display field3.